# Inline x86 asm for dividing by 2 in C

Tags: assembly, inline-assembly

Im trying to convert something in C

```
int div
div = div/2;
```

into inline ATT x86 assembly using right shift (SAR)

```
asm("sar %0" : "=r"(div));
```

but I couldn't get it to work. 
Any insights would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Isn't this something any decent compiler already knows how to do?

Comment: @Thilo Yes, but let's say for the sake of learning, I would still very much like to know the correct way of writing something like that.

Comment: Any decent compiler knows /2 is >>1, and any decent programmer knows >>1 is /2.

Comment: But hold on! Signed division by two is *not* a signed right shift by 1. Try a negative number and see how it works out.

Comment: @harold >>1 is still /2 on negatives except it rounding away from 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `=r`, you are telling the compiler that the existing value in div is overwritten by the asm.  To tell it you are both reading and writing the value of div in the asm, use `+r` (see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Modifiers.html):

```
asm("sar %0" : "+r"(div));
```

Comment: Have my +1 for being one of those inline-GAS-black-magicians.

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you for answer and the link. Will read up on it now.